# Why indirect increment is faster than direct inc?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

The question had been asked by another SO member, but was disappointingly deleted. The comments were saying the measurements are flawed and does not make sense.

However I was able to reproduce the original problem with a small benchmark under [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class LoopInc {

    private int getValue() {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int directInc() {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            switch (getValue()) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int indirectInc() {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            boolean incr = false;
            switch (getValue()) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    incr = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (incr) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include("bench.LoopInc.*")
                .warmupIterations(5)
                .measurementIterations(10)
                .forks(3)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }
}
```

The benchmarks shows `indirectInc` works 3 times faster, though the "optimization" is not obvious at all. One would assume `indirectInc` should work a bit slower because it involves an extra intermediate operation.

```
Benchmark             Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
LoopInc.directInc    thrpt   30  127,301 ± 0,202  ops/ms
LoopInc.indirectInc  thrpt   30  378,147 ± 1,144  ops/ms
```

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

What causes JIT to compile `indirectInc` better than similar `directInc`?

Comment: How are you benchmarking this?

Comment: Something wrong with your Benchmark approach, for sure. Question is: what?

Comment: Could be a warm-up issue. Try reversing the order of your tests

Comment: I did a reliable test, results: `d: 4.2122468E-5,i: 4.041445E-5`. `d` is direct, `i` is indirect (measured in seconds; 500 times each method; when increasing to 5000 times, direct are nearly 2x slower)

Comment: I believe it is a kind of CPU/JVM optimization

Comment: i think you can get JMH to print assembly output, that would be informative here. also make sure that it gets compiled with C2.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: @Kon For sure. Please tell me what :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel Could be. What would you suggest?

Comment: @kamil09875 Yes, that's what the question is about - what kind of optimization?

Comment: Your random is likely to be far more expensive than the rest of your code.  The answer is likely to be based on which optimisations the C2 compiler recognises and which ones it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know random is expensive, but it does not matter. Even if I change `getValue` to return pregenerated sequence, `indirectInc` will be still significantly faster.

Comment: @apangin I suggest you have a look at the assembly produced using JITWatch.  I expect the faster version will have been optimised more heavily e.g. with loop unrolling.

Comment: Dump the bytecodes and see what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for insisting and good question preparation using JMH.

Comment: @ControlAltDel JMH does typically a very good job in warm-ups and repeats. And the small error hints in the direction of a pretty stable result

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Ok, this is how you approach these things.

1. Try to reproduce it. Okay, it reproduces:

   ```
   Benchmark             Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
   LoopInc.directInc    thrpt   15  175.678 ± 1.118  ops/ms
   LoopInc.indirectInc  thrpt   15  641.413 ± 9.722  ops/ms
   ```
2. Try to see the generated assembly with `-prof perfasm`. Long story short, it produces a lot of generated code, and so we probably want to limit the loop unrolling. But, it can affect the performance, and can pretty much be the cause. So, let's re-run with `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1`. Okay, the score is lower, but the difference is still there, excellent:

   ```
   Benchmark             Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
   LoopInc.directInc    thrpt   15  161.147 ± 6.101  ops/ms
   LoopInc.indirectInc  thrpt   15  489.430 ± 1.698  ops/ms
   ```
3. Take another look at the generated code, still nothing that pops out to our eye. Well, this seems interesting. Let's get on this properly. Can we characterize the workload? Of course we can, with the help of `-prof perfnorm`, which normalizes the hardware counters per benchmark op. Let's see:

   ```
   Benchmark                                     Mode  Cnt      Score      Error   Units
   LoopInc.directInc                            thrpt   15    161.875 ±    3.038  ops/ms
   LoopInc.directInc:·CPI                       thrpt    3      0.967 ±    0.196    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·L1-dcache-load-misses     thrpt    3      0.394 ±    3.663    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·L1-dcache-loads           thrpt    3   2149.594 ±  228.166    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·L1-dcache-store-misses    thrpt    3      0.114 ±    1.001    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·L1-dcache-stores          thrpt    3   1073.666 ±   96.066    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·L1-icache-load-misses     thrpt    3      0.965 ±   22.984    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·LLC-loads                 thrpt    3      0.204 ±    2.763    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·LLC-stores                thrpt    3      0.060 ±    0.633    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·branch-misses             thrpt    3    536.068 ±   43.293    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·branches                  thrpt    3   3728.890 ±  220.539    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·cycles                    thrpt    3  26219.146 ± 6287.590    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·dTLB-load-misses          thrpt    3      0.063 ±    0.124    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·dTLB-loads                thrpt    3   2136.942 ±  165.990    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·dTLB-store-misses         thrpt    3      0.022 ±    0.029    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·dTLB-stores               thrpt    3   1084.787 ±  417.281    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·iTLB-load-misses          thrpt    3      0.081 ±    0.333    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·iTLB-loads                thrpt    3      3.623 ±   19.955    #/op
   LoopInc.directInc:·instructions              thrpt    3  27114.052 ± 1843.720    #/op

   LoopInc.indirectInc                          thrpt   15    489.164 ±    2.692  ops/ms
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·CPI                     thrpt    3      0.281 ±    0.015    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·L1-dcache-load-misses   thrpt    3      0.503 ±    9.071    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·L1-dcache-loads         thrpt    3   2149.806 ±  369.040    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·L1-dcache-store-misses  thrpt    3      0.167 ±    1.370    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·L1-dcache-stores        thrpt    3   1073.895 ±  186.741    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·L1-icache-load-misses   thrpt    3      0.313 ±    1.275    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·branch-misses           thrpt    3      1.102 ±    0.375    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·branches                thrpt    3   2143.670 ±  228.475    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·cycles                  thrpt    3   8701.665 ±  706.183    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·dTLB-load-misses        thrpt    3      0.020 ±    0.301    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·dTLB-loads              thrpt    3   2141.965 ±  135.852    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·dTLB-store-misses       thrpt    3      0.002 ±    0.029    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·dTLB-stores             thrpt    3   1070.376 ±   81.445    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·iTLB-load-misses        thrpt    3      0.007 ±    0.135    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·iTLB-loads              thrpt    3      0.310 ±    5.768    #/op
   LoopInc.indirectInc:·instructions            thrpt    3  30968.207 ± 3627.540    #/op
   ```

   Oh, both benchmarks have comparable number of instructions. The slower one takes more cycles (that's why CPI is also not ideal in `directInc`; `indirectInc`, however, produces a close-to-ideal CPI). If you look closely at possible causes: there is not many cache misses, not many TLB misses, but slow benchmark has lots of branch misses. AHA! Now we know what to look in the generated code.
4. Let's look at generated code again. `-prof perfasm` conveniently highlights the jumps. And then you will see this...

   **directInc**:

   ```
                     ╭│      0x00007fa0a82a50ff: jmp    0x00007fa0a82a5116
    11.39%   16.90%  ││ ↗    0x00007fa0a82a5101: inc    %edx               ;*iinc
                     ││ │                                                  ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::directInc@46 (line 18)
    12.52%   23.11%  ││ │↗↗  0x00007fa0a82a5103: mov    %r10,0xe8(%r11)    ;*invokevirtual putLong
                     ││ │││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::nextSeed@27 (line 241)
    12.00%    8.14%  ││ │││  0x00007fa0a82a510a: inc    %r8d               ;*iinc
                     ││ │││                                                ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::directInc@46 (line 18)
     0.03%    0.03%  ││ │││  0x00007fa0a82a510d: cmp    $0x3e8,%r8d
                     │╰ │││  0x00007fa0a82a5114: jge    0x00007fa0a82a50c7  ;*aload_0
                     │  │││                                                ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::directInc@11 (line 19)
     0.80%    0.91%  ↘  │││  0x00007fa0a82a5116: mov    0xf0(%r11),%r10d   ;*invokevirtual getInt
                        │││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::current@9 (line 222)
     4.28%    1.23%     │││  0x00007fa0a82a511d: test   %r10d,%r10d
                       ╭│││  0x00007fa0a82a5120: je     0x00007fa0a82a517b  ;*ifne
                       ││││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::current@12 (line 222)
     2.11%    0.01%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5122: movabs $0x9e3779b97f4a7c15,%r10
     0.01%    0.07%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a512c: add    0xe8(%r11),%r10    ;*ladd
                       ││││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::nextSeed@24 (line 242)
     7.73%    1.89%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5133: mov    %r10,%r9
     1.21%    1.84%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5136: shr    $0x21,%r9
     1.90%    0.03%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a513a: xor    %r10,%r9
     2.02%    0.03%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a513d: movabs $0xff51afd7ed558ccd,%rcx
     0.94%    1.82%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5147: imul   %rcx,%r9           ;*lmul
                       ││││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::mix32@9 (line 182)
     7.01%    2.40%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a514b: mov    %r9,%rcx
                       ││││  0x00007fa0a82a514e: shr    $0x21,%rcx
     1.89%    0.70%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5152: xor    %r9,%rcx
     3.11%    2.55%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5155: movabs $0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53,%r9
     0.99%    1.50%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a515f: imul   %r9,%rcx
     7.66%    2.89%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5163: shr    $0x20,%rcx
     3.70%    1.97%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a5167: mov    %ecx,%r9d
              0.11%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a516a: and    $0x1,%r9d          ;*iand
                       ││││                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::nextInt@34 (line 356)
     3.76%   11.13%    ││││  0x00007fa0a82a516e: cmp    $0x1,%r9d
                       │╰││  0x00007fa0a82a5172: je     0x00007fa0a82a5101
    10.48%   16.62%    │ ││  0x00007fa0a82a5174: test   %r9d,%r9d
                       │ ╰│  0x00007fa0a82a5177: je     0x00007fa0a82a5103  ;*lookupswitch
                       │  │                                                ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::directInc@15 (line 19)
                       │  ╰  0x00007fa0a82a5179: jmp    0x00007fa0a82a5103  ;*aload_0
                       │                                                   ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::directInc@11 (line 19)
                       ↘     0x00007fa0a82a517b: mov    $0xffffff5d,%esi
   ```

   **indirectInc**:

   ```
     0.01%    0.01%  ↗  0x00007f65588d8260: mov    %edx,%r9d
     0.01%           │  0x00007f65588d8263: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    11.99%   11.38%  │  0x00007f65588d826c: data16 data16 xchg %ax,%ax  ;*iconst_0
                     │                                                ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::indirectInc@11 (line 34)
                     │  0x00007f65588d8270: mov    0xf0(%r8),%r10d    ;*invokevirtual getInt
                     │                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::current@9 (line 222)
                     │  0x00007f65588d8277: test   %r10d,%r10d
                     │  0x00007f65588d827a: je     0x00007f65588d8331  ;*ifne
                     │                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::current@12 (line 222)
     0.01%           │  0x00007f65588d8280: movabs $0x9e3779b97f4a7c15,%r10
    11.80%   11.49%  │  0x00007f65588d828a: add    0xe8(%r8),%r10     ;*ladd
                     │                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::nextSeed@24 (line 242)
     0.01%    0.01%  │  0x00007f65588d8291: mov    %r10,0xe8(%r8)     ;*invokevirtual putLong
                     │                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::nextSeed@27 (line 241)
                     │  0x00007f65588d8298: mov    %r9d,%edx
     0.01%    0.01%  │  0x00007f65588d829b: inc    %edx
    11.12%   12.40%  │  0x00007f65588d829d: mov    %r10,%rcx
              0.01%  │  0x00007f65588d82a0: shr    $0x21,%rcx
     0.03%           │  0x00007f65588d82a4: xor    %r10,%rcx
     0.06%    0.03%  │  0x00007f65588d82a7: movabs $0xff51afd7ed558ccd,%r10
    12.38%   13.94%  │  0x00007f65588d82b1: imul   %r10,%rcx          ;*lmul
                     │                                                ; - java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom::mix32@9 (line 182)
     0.03%    0.01%  │  0x00007f65588d82b5: mov    %rcx,%r10
                     │  0x00007f65588d82b8: shr    $0x21,%r10
              0.03%  │  0x00007f65588d82bc: xor    %rcx,%r10
    11.43%   12.62%  │  0x00007f65588d82bf: movabs $0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53,%rcx
              0.01%  │  0x00007f65588d82c9: imul   %rcx,%r10
     0.34%    0.30%  │  0x00007f65588d82cd: shr    $0x20,%r10
     0.85%    0.76%  │  0x00007f65588d82d1: mov    %r10d,%r10d
    11.81%   11.51%  │  0x00007f65588d82d4: and    $0x1,%r10d
     2.16%    1.78%  │  0x00007f65588d82d8: cmp    $0x1,%r10d
     3.45%    3.00%  │  0x00007f65588d82dc: cmovne %r9d,%edx         <----- HERE IT IS
    17.55%   15.86%  │  0x00007f65588d82e0: inc    %r11d              ;*iinc
                     │                                                ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::indirectInc@56 (line 33)
                     │  0x00007f65588d82e3: cmp    $0x3e8,%r11d
                     ╰  0x00007f65588d82ea: jl     0x00007f65588d8260  ;*if_icmpge
                                                              ; - org.openjdk.LoopInc::indirectInc@8 (line 33)
   ```

   Notice the `cmovne` instead of `jmp` -- this is why we have more "predictable" branches. HotSpot profiles the branches, and emits the conditional move when the branch profile branch is very flat. In other words, dodge a very likely branch misprediction by paying a bit for the added latency of conditional move. However, in this case, switch is special: it has *more than two* alternatives (0, 1, and "nothing"). This is why, I speculate, the `result` increment is not being folded into cmov. (Generally speaking, HotSpot could have stored zero to `result` in "default", but it blew it, oh well)
5. To confirm that hypothesis, let's make a `directCompleteInc` case, where we still use `switch`, but now cover all the cases:

   ```
   @Benchmark
   public int directCompleteInc() {
       int result = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
           switch (getValue()) {
               case 1:
                   result++;
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

   ...and measure it, and this time without any options, like the OP did:

   ```
   Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt    Score    Error   Units
   LoopInc.directCompleteInc  thrpt    5  644.414 ±  0.371  ops/ms
   LoopInc.directInc          thrpt    5  174.974 ±  0.103  ops/ms
   LoopInc.indirectInc        thrpt    5  644.015 ±  0.533  ops/ms
   ```

   THERE.
6. Confirm `directCompleteInc` is using `cmov` with `-prof perfasm`. It does.
7. Drink up.

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed `cmov` instead of `jmp` in the generated assembly and verified that both cases work equally slow if I disable `cmov`s with `-XX:ConditionalMoveLimit=0`. But it is still unclear why HotSpot cannot generate `cmov` in the first case. I've also checked that both cases work equally fast if I replace random sequence with a predictable one, so that `perf` reports much smaller number of mispredicted branches. Anyway, this is a great answer!

Comment: BTW, is there an analogue of `-prof perfnorm` for Windows?

Comment: @apangin: Windows has `-prof xperfasm`, but not `perfnorm`. I am not aware of `perf stat` alternative for Windows, so...

Comment: @apangin: My guess is that the IR shape that non-complete switch is generating does confuse the `cmov` folding, since there are more than two branches. But, that's a speculation, you tell me ;)

Comment: Once again great answer and methodology lesson. Just want to add to it: while this has found a good point of (failed) micro optimization in the JVM, I guess there are nearly no occassions where it really matters (and where you can actually replicate the wrong/right optimisation, perhaps?)

Comment: A complex environment like JVM is full of these small dusty corners where something does not go the way you'd like. If those minute differences matter to you (= you actually seen them as problems), then you can use the methodology like the above to avoid them. Also, toy examples provide an opportunity to learn on simple cases before diving head-first into the real life ones.